# Check for new information in a webpage flask

Tags: python, flask

I have this game I'm making (trying to make a copy of quiplash from jackbox) and i have a wait page to wait for everyone to answer but the only way I've thought of updating the page once all the players have answered is checking if they have and if they havent then reload the page which will loop reload but some browsers dont like that. Here is my code (the printing was debugging purposes):

```
@app.route("/wait")
def wait():
    if(not "answered" in session):
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    else:
        print(len(answers))
        print(len(players))
        if(len(answers) == len(players)):
            return redirect(url_for("the_answers"))
        else:
            return render_template("wait.html")
```

This is wait.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Wait</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/wait"><button>Try again</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i check for updates without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Javascript` so you can do things without reloading the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#form_id').submit(function(event) {
            // when a user submits an answer, do something
            // like add a message in HTML "Waiting for others.."
            // or send a message to your `server` that this person is done. 
            // You can send update via websocket to your server
        });
    });
</script>
```

If this is a multiplayer game, you might need a server to consolidate all the answers. Try looking into `websockets` to do this. I've used `flask-socketio`.

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/